# Spark Medium of values as column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, mean

I just starting to work with Spark and I have to create a column with values based on another data frame values. My first data frame has an **Id** and **start date** columns while my other one has a **yield value**,**acquired date** and **Id**. I have to create a new column in the first data frame with the  mean of the available values from the last 30 days of the start date with the yield values from the other data frame. So the output should look something like this:

Table 1

```
ID  start_date
1    01/12/2018
2    01/11/2019
```

Table 2

```
ID   yield acquired_date
1    120   05/11/2019
1    100   05/11/2018
1    200   07/11/2018
1    200   08/11/2018
2    350   04/10/2020
2    300   04/10/2019
2    100   05/10/2019
```

output

```
ID  start_date  yield_mean
1    01/12/2018   250
2    01/11/2019   200
```

Note: the mean only accounts for values where acquired date is 30 days less than start date so row 0 and row 4 are not used.

Comment: Have you tried join two data frames by ID and date with operators?

Comment: Since I am new to Spark I don't know much about date operation, could you provide an example?